# Remove attributes from DOMElement only works when iterating backwards

Tags: php, attributes, domdocument

*Background Info*: I use PHP5.4.9 from Ubuntu 13.04 repository. The aim of my code is to iterate HTML source (as a [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php)) recursively and cleanup everything that is not valid to be used inside Epub files (i.e. and attribute align is not valid for paragraphs in Epubs).

Example input:

```
<p lang="de" class="foo" style="align: left;">... some content ...</p>
```

Desired output:

```
<p class="foo">... some content ...</p>
```

---

*1*: Today I tried removing attributes from a [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domelement.php) using this simple code:

```
<?php
for ( $k=0; $k < $element->attributes->length; $k++) {
    if( /* some rule */ ){
        var_dump( $element->attributes->item($k)->nodeName);
        $element->removeAttributeNode( $element->attributes->item($k));
    }
}
?>
```

Unfortunately all attributes still existed when this loop was finished, even if these var_dumps told me that deleting them was tried.

I solved this problem iterating the attributes list backward:

```
<?php
for ( $k = $element->attributes->length - 1; $k >= 0; --$k) {
    if( /* same rule */ ){
        var_dump( $element->attributes->item($k)->nodeName);
        $element->removeAttributeNode( $element->attributes->item($k));
    }
}
?>
```

*Question*: Any ideas why it's only working when iterating backwards ?

---

*2*: [DOMElement::removeAttributeNode](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattributenode.php) does NOT return a bool but a DOMAttr object.

*Question*: Is this an error in the php.net manual or am I doing/understanding something wrong ?

---

It works for now but it would be great to know WHY it's only working this way. 
Thank you in advanced

Comment: I can't tell why the attributes didn't get deleted, but it is usually a bad idea to iterate over a container while you are modifying it.

Comment: I've tried what you mentioned before with the same result.
So in the first step save all attributes that need to be deleted.
Then in second step, after the first iteration finished, I tried to remove these attributes. They still exist afterwards.

Comment: Doing it back-to front is OK too. While it doesn't really explain your problem, it is the Right Thing To Do™ when removing stuff from an array.